# Qt Creator / C++ does valgrind make sense in this case

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm used to using valgrind to debug my C code, but I recently switch to Qt Creator and C++.  Qt Creator has valgrind built in which sounds good but...

if I don't malloc/free memory directly (i.e. only use C++'s built in memory cleanup upon no more references to objects), shouldn't memory leaks be impossible?

How could I cause a memory leak if C++ is managing the objects and memory....

(I fear a RTFM answer, but scratching head)

---

What about something like this:

```
m_logFile = new QFile(programSettings->logging_filename());
```

would I have to free what this pointer points to, or when m_logFile no longer points to a valid object will the memory be freed?  (Since I use 'new' here I wonder if it works differently)

Comment: The library itself may have some memory leaks (if you're using Qt some returned things require you to explicitly free them IIRC).

Comment: Unles you `delete` that's a memory leak. Every `new` must have a matching `delete`, otherwise it's a memory leak. The way to avoid memory leaks is not to use pointers.

Comment: The Qt way of doing things seems to be freeing (with `delete`) things up in the destructors of classes that you allocate in your (usually QObject-inheriting) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt's memory management is only automatic for `QObject` hierarchies, where the parent owns the children. As long as you destruct the parent, all of the children will get deleted. This of course applies to `QWidgets`, as they are `QObject`s. Technically, you could make just a `QObject` be a parent of a `QWidget`, but it breaks down the assumptions that widgets have about their parents, so don't do that. A `QWidget` can of course own `QObject`s.

Here's the *very important detail*: it's the *destruction* of the parent that *destructs and deletes* the children. The parent may be an automatic variable, and then the memory is deallocated automatically upon leaving the scope. If the parent is allocated on the free store using `new`, you've got yourself a memory leak unless:

1. You manually `delete` the parent.
2. You use a smart pointer.

Generally speaking, using naked pointers in C++ should be avoided. Qt provides a `QSharedPointer` that's mostly equivalent to C++11's `std::shared_ptr`, and a `QScopedPointer` that's mostly equivalent to C++11's `std::unique_ptr`. Use them unless you've got measurements showing that manual memory management will win you something in terms of performance or memory overhead. Those smart pointers perform the exception-safe memory management for you.

I think you would benefit from reading Strostrup's "The C++ Programming Language", 4th edition. It introduces those concepts with more depth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case valgrind is still useful.  C++ (even with Qt) is still not a garbage collected language, so you can still accidentally leak memory.  In the example code you gave,  the QFile will leak as nothing will destroy it (by using the delete operator).

Qt does provide a method to help cleanup any QObject derived classes.  However, you still need to pass the correct object as the parent object for the cleanup to work.

Also, valgrind will also help identify any incorrect uses of uninitialised or freed memory.